Can't UPLOAD on s3 bucket with Laravel (always returns false)
I'm simply trying to upload anything on my AWS s3 bucket.
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

my .env file contains every necessery keys and infos. I followed many tutorials, all doing the same things, that I did, multiple time.
The steps are as follow:
Create an IAM user, with s3FullAccess permissions.
Generate access keys.
Create bucket. Followed https://laravel-news.com/using-aws-s3-for-laravel-storage instruction to the letter (minimal security on the bucket for testing purposes)
filled the .env file with IAM user keys, bucket region, bucket name
Used a upload input first, validated in the controller to be uploaded.
Currently using a more direct approach:
Route::get('/', function () {
    try {
        $result = Storage::disk('s3')->put('test.txt', 'This is a test file.');    
        dd($result);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('S3 Upload Error: ' . $e->getMessage());    }
   
});```

the dd always return false. So did the upload input of previous aproach. Tried many buckets, many regions, many users. Always false.

I might be the only morron not capable of making it work, since the steps are not that complicated, and I can't find much on google.

Using PhP 8.3, last version of Laravel (breeze and typescript). Local devellopment (php artisan serve).



It was a tricky one.
While trying to create the bucket through s3 client (I was desperate...):
 $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        ]
    ]);

    if (!$s3->doesBucketExist(env('AWS_BUCKET'))) {
        // Create bucket if it doesn't exist
        try{
            $s3->createBucket([
                'Bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'Bucket Creation Failed' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }

I got
{"Bucket Creation Failed":"Error executing \"CreateBucket\" on \"https:\/\/helenebucketparis.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com\/\"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https:\/\/curl.haxx.se\/libcurl\/c\/libcurl-errors.html) for https:\/\/helenebucketparis.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com\/"}

So I had to:

download the cacert.pem from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
go to my php.ini file (in the PHP folder) and modify the line:
curl.cainfo = "C:\path\to\your\cacert.pem"

Everything works now. If that can help someone one day.
